# Can not send multiple KeyCodes to Android Box

Tags: android, keyevent, keycode, dispatch

When I press on DEL button it sends an event which deletes one characteristic from edittext. When I press and hold the DEL button it deletes again only one characteristic. So the goal is to delete all characteristics when the DEL button is long pressed.

The code bellow I write in my OnTouchListener ( KeyCode 69 is responsible for deleting ):

```
Key mKey = new Key(RemoteIME.mService, 0, 69);
sendCmdMessage(SendThread.CMD_SEND_KEY, event.getAction(), 0, mKey);
```

And here is the code for sending commands to Android Box:

```
private void sendCmdMessage(int what, int arg1, int arg2, Object obj) {
    if( mSendCmdHandler != null ) {
        Message msg = Message.obtain();
        msg.what = what;
        msg.arg1 = arg1;
        msg.arg2 = arg2;
        msg.obj = obj;
        mSendCmdHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
    else {
        mSendCmdHandler = mSendThread.getHandler();
        Log.d(TAG, "mSendCmdHandler is null!");
    }
}
```

I have tried to send the delete command in loop ( for example when press DEL I send the command 5 times ), but it aging deletes only one characteristic.

So how can I solve the problem ?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Can you be more clear, is the problem you can't delete all the text or don't know how to achieve LongPress ?

Comment: Hello, the problem is that I can't delete all the text.